# Ruby Signal Trapper priority

Tags: ruby, linux, signals

In Ruby, I'm well aware that the most recently registered signal trapper is the one that takes precedence, so:

```
Signal.trap("TERM") {puts "foo"; exit}
Signal.trap("TERM") {puts "bar"; exit}
```

If I were to issue a 'kill' to the above script, it would print out "bar" and exit.

Is there a way, in Ruby itself, to enforce some sort of scope for trappers?

My specific situation is this:

We have an application that defines its own trapper (for this story, we'll just say it only traps "TERM") in a namespaced Signals module. That code is required into the app at runtime and pretty much left alone after that.

A 3rd-party gem (I won't name names) we use, actually registers its own trapper for "TERM" *in the initialize method*, so the most recently initialized object will be the one to handle the "TERM" signal for the entire application with undesirable results...

While it may make sense for the 3rd party gems' objects to have their own trappers defined, I don't want them affecting my app.

Is anyone aware of a way to give the non-initialize-non-3rd-party trapper precedence without getting too fancy?

Comment: That sounds like a bad bug in the third-party gem...what happens if it has multiple objects? Does it have some means of calling handlers on all of its live objects?

Comment: It does, but it's not really relevant to the signal trapping as the most recently registered trapper for a given signal will be the one that Ruby always uses for that signal. I'm not sure if that's default behavior of Ruby or if it's configurable or what. (Although I agree it's probably not desirable behavior in the 3rd party gem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could monkey patch `Signal` to alias `Signal.trap` and then replace it with a no-op:

```
module Signal
    class << self
        alias_method :real_trap, :trap
        def trap(*) end
    end
end
```

Then you can use `real_trap` in your code and this rude unnamed gem you're using will be ignored. You'd have to make sure `Signal` was patched before your rude-gem did anything though.

With that patch in place, sending a SIGTERM to this code:

```
Signal.trap("TERM") {puts "foo"; exit}
Signal.trap("TERM") {puts "bar"; exit}
Signal.real_trap("TERM") {puts "pancakes"; exit}
```

would give you pancakes.

I generally try to avoid monkey patching but it is quite useful for kludging around bugs and other bad behavior.

Comment: Or alternatively monkey-patch or fork the gem.

Comment: @Andrew: That's an option as well, depends on how much stuff there is wrapped around the `Signal.trap` call.

Comment: I actually hadn't considered monkey patching Signal, but I was hoping to avoid monkey patching altogether. It's looking like I'll have to bust that out for this specific issue. I'm going to be providing a  patch for the gem in question (it hasn't been touched in a couple years from what I can see, so might have to end up forking it). I'll leave this open for a little bit longer to see if anyone else has anything to say, if not, answer's yours @muistooshort

Comment: This approach is a last resort but sometimes you have to do unpleasant things to work around bugs (yes, I'd call the gem's behavior a bug) and rudeness (the gem is also being rude). Sometimes you have to hold your nose, clear the kids out of the room, and brutalize things into sensibility :) Hacking the gem's source or monkey patching the gem to remove the `trap` calls are other unpleasant options.

Comment: I submitted a pull request, and we'll probably build our own custom version of the gem if another release doesn't come out soon. Thanks for the thoughts. Appreciate it.